# Spring JPA how to create an object with relationship to another entity in Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a Person with an Address, each of them are an entity. My Entities seem to work, the part where i begin to struggle is on how to create a Person using the constructor where i also have to put in the Address.

```
personRepository.save(new Person(new Name("Test","Test"),new Adress("Street","Number","PLZ","Town"),LocalDate.parse("2000-01-01"),"email@email.com","911");
```

**This sadly does not work so my question is how can i create a Person object with the Address.**

**I'm also wondering how i would add the address if i already got the address in my Address repository, is there a way to get the address or use the adress ID?**

```
adresseRepository.save(new Adresse("Street","Number","PLZ","Town"));
```

Here's the code for both of the shortend.

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PersonID")
    private Long personID;
    @Column(name = "FullName")
    @Convert(converter = NameConverter.class)
    private Name fullName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="AdresseID")
    private Adresse adresse;
    @Column(name = "Geburtsdatum")
    private LocalDate geburtsdatum;
    @Column(name = "EMail")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "Telefonnummer")
    private String telefonnummer;

    private Person() {}

    public Person(Name fullName, Adresse adresse, LocalDate geburtsdatum, String email, String telefonnummer) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.geburtsdatum = geburtsdatum;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefonnummer = telefonnummer;
    }
}
```

Address:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Adresse")
public class Adresse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "AdresseID")
    private Long adresseID;
    @Column(name = "Strasse")
    private String strasse;
    @Column(name = "Hausnummer")
    private String hausnummer;
    @Column(name = "PLZ")
    private String plz;
    @Column(name = "Ort")
    private String ort;

    protected Adresse() {}

    public Adresse(String strasse, String hausnummer, String plz, String ort) {
        this.strasse = strasse;
        this.hausnummer = hausnummer;
        this.plz = plz;
        this.ort = ort;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ralationships are created in hibernate like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
    private Set<Item> items;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

Please note that the @OneToMany annotation is used to define the property in Item class that will be used to map the mappedBy variable. That is why we have a property named “cart” in the Item class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Item {
    
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    private Cart cart;

    public Item() {}
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

Soin your case you just have to add

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")

public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
private User user;
```

something lilke this to your Adress Table.
Because one Adress also have one user.

[For more information visit this site](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one)

Comment: Thanks it added this to my source code. But i still got the issue that if i use the same adress for two users the adress gets added twice instead of just having it once in the database